# Connect iOS device to Bluetooth device with SPP

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gatt, spp, ancs

I'm working on one watch which shows iOS device notification like..

- Display Installed app notification
- Display Call notification
- Display Message notification.. etc

I have read some articles and came to know about GATT and ANCS, and this two itself enough to display iOS device notification on other bluetooth device.

- Generic Attribute(GATT) Profile : https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/GATT.aspx
- Apple Notification Center Service(ANCS):
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

Is that mean I do not need any iOS application to handle iOS device notification?

Currently my watch is built up with SPP, do I need to make any modification in that?

I also came to know that I have to apply for MFi Program(https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

is MFi necessary for My watch with the idea I have mentioned above?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SPP is classic BT whereas ANCS uses BTLE. 
ANCS is free to use. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW18